# Plugins in Cpp - Executing external program functions

Tags: c++, plugins

I was wondering if there is any way to make something like plugin in Java, so main program loads sub-programs and execute their functions. I thought about set of small programs that return some value, but I want to make the plugins able to modify some of the main program objects (maybe pass the pointer somehow?).

Is there any way to do this?

Thanx for any replies.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to dynamically load code at run-time in the form of dynamically linked libraries (DLL:s in Windows).

The approach (when dealing with Windows at least) I use is about this:

- Create a dll with some exported functions (declared with __declspec(dllexport))
- Load the created file at run-time with the LoadLibrary function in the Windows-API
- Get the function-pointer to a member function by its name with the function GetProcAddress-function using the name of the function.

The last part may be a little confusing sometimes as C++ uses name-mangling to keep track of return types and such things. This means that the name stored in the DLL is not the name of the function, but a name also containing descriptions of the function's parameter types and such things.

To prevent the name-mangling, you can declare the exported functions with extern "C", such as

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int myFunction(...);
```

However, this will not allow for classes in the function declaration.

An important thing to consider when passing pointers to data structures between the dynamically linked library and the "main program" is to make sure that the declaration of the type is the same in the two files (easily accomplished by sharing the header declaring the type), otherwise there will be severe errors when executing your program.

Again, this is probably Windows-specific, but it might give you a hint of the correct procedure on your system.

Comment: It's the same on all platforms, pretty much: use "C" name-mangling rather than C++, the plugins can't throw out exceptions, write out classes and their methods explicitly as structs and functions taking pointers to them, and so on. dlopen (or LoadLibrary) load the file into your address space, and dlsym (or GetProcAddress) look up function pointers for you in the list of exported symbols. Very tidy and clear, more so than a language like Java!

Comment: Wait, so you mean if I use DLL, I can also use it on Linux and I can modify the main programs custom classes from the plugin?

Comment: @Nicholas Wilson upper post was to you :D

Comment: Well, you can certainly write cross-platform C++ that will compile on linux and Windows, to create a shared library with the same functionality of each. You'll have to compile twice though of course, to make a binary for each platform: you can't run Win32 code on linux, and certainly not the other way round either! The code in the DLL gets loaded into your process's address space: it can most definitely modify variables and objects in the main process. It's just mapping the contents of the binary on disk into your process's address space and giving an ordinary function pointer to it.